# How are differences in R2 of two models with/without variable A related to the (partial) eta2 of variable A in the extended model?

Tags: r-squared

Assume I have two models:

m1: Y = B0 + B1*X1 + e

m2: Y = B0 + B1*X1 + B2*X2 + e

How is the difference in R-squared between m1 and m2 related to the (partial) eta-squared of B2 in m2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeterminate.  What does exactly specify the difference between the r-squared of the two models is the *semipartial* r-squared of X2, also known as its part r-squared.  This tells the amount of r-squared *uniquely*, or incrementally, accounted for by X2.

You can contrast this with the partial r-squared (aka the partial eta-squared), which identifies the relationship between X2 and Y when X1 is controlled. The partial r-squared will be similar to the standardized regression coefficient and allows an estimate of the direction and strength of the relationship with Y.  The semipartial is a different animal; it's all about the portion of the predictive contribution that's unique to each predictor.  The semipartial will always be <= the partial.

Comment: Thanks, this helps! When you mention semipartial r-squared, is this the same as eta-squared (not the partial eta-squared)?

Comment: In many cases you can essentially substitute r for eta or verse-vica.